# Had decided or decided in this context?

Tags: past-tense

I don't remember exactly when I first heard of you. I think it was  when I received the very first xxxx single ,

I had read a good review of it and  **decided** to order it . I received it with a letter from the band  and I think the name of the label was written in this letter but I am not sure .

Shall I write "had decided" because this action is situated before receiving  the single. However I don't think so because with the first past perfect the action is already situated before the reception and all actions (reading, ordering and receiving are in chronological order) . Am I right here?

Comment: The temporal relationship is already established by initial ***had read***, so although it's logically and syntactically "valid" to use Past Perfect again for ***had decided***, it's not *necessary*. And the default principle is *Don't use a Perfect form if you don't need it*, so most native Anglophones *wouldn't* repeat it there. Where would you stop? *I **had received** it?* *I **had thought** the name...?*

Comment: I should perhaps add that I don't see any point in using Past Perfect ***at all*** in the cited text. The fact that you must have read the review *before* deciding to place an order is so obvious there's no need to explicitly underline it by using Past Perfect for the earlier action of reading the review. Better to stick to Simple Past throughout, then you won't be tempted to keep plugging away with Perfect forms right up to *...I think the name of the label **had been written** in this letter...*